# Trouble verifying covariance of differential calculus of the two dimensional quantum plane

Tags: noncommutative-geometry

I'm looking at page 4 and 5 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/math-ph/0105002.pdf. I am wanting to use (14) and (17) to verify the covariance of (14). But I'm having trouble, in particular, I'm having trouble
proving $\frac{\partial}{\partial X'} Y' = q Y' \frac{\partial}{\partial X'}$. Here is what I have calculated:

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial X'} Y' & = \left( D \frac{\partial}{\partial X} - q C \frac{\partial}{\partial Y} \right)(C X + DY)
\\
& = DC \frac{\partial}{\partial X} X + D^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial X} Y - q C^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial Y} X - q CD \frac{\partial}{\partial Y} Y
\\
& = DC \left( q^2 X \frac{\partial}{\partial X} + 1 + (q^2 - 1) Y \frac{\partial}{\partial Y} \right) + q D^2 Y \frac{\partial}{\partial X} - q^2 C^2 X \frac{\partial}{\partial Y} - q CD \left( 1 + q^2 Y \frac{\partial}{\partial Y} \right)
\\
& = q CD X \frac{\partial}{\partial X} - q^2 C^2 X \frac{\partial}{\partial Y} + q D^2 Y \frac{\partial}{\partial X} + DC \left( 1 + (q^2 - 1) Y \frac{\partial}{\partial Y} - q^2 - q^4 Y \frac{\partial}{\partial Y}  \right)
\end{align}

This doesn't seem to match $q Y' \frac{\partial}{\partial X'}$:

\begin{align}
q Y' \frac{\partial}{\partial X'} & = q (CX + DY) \left( D \frac{\partial}{\partial X} - q C \frac{\partial}{\partial Y} \right)
\\
& = q CD X \frac{\partial}{\partial X} - q^2 C^2 X \frac{\partial}{\partial Y} + q D^2 Y \frac{\partial}{\partial X} - q^2 DC Y  \frac{\partial}{\partial Y}
\end{align}

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Check out this article: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0920563291901433 I believe this is the origin of the differential calculus here.

Comment: Hi @CameronWilliams. Thanks for the reference. I've been seriously preoccupied. I'm just starting going through the paper. But is there not enough definitions/facts given in https://arxiv.org/pdf/math-ph/0105002.pdf to deduce covariance?

Comment: No, not at all. I kept running into contradictions because the differential calculus behaves differently and they do not explain how. The link I shared does, unfortunately it's a bit dense for me, but it seems like the differential (d) plays a crucial role. Skipping that and going straight to the derivatives ($\partial$) changes the picture a lot.